# Solr json response needs all highlighted docs

Tags: solr, jsonp, highlighting

I need to be able to type in a query in the search textfield in my web app and return highlighted results from each document that has the specific text. The problem is, I can't get the response to show all documents, it only shows one.

Lets say I have 4 documents with ID of doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4 etc. How can I get the code to loop through to display content from all 4 documents rather than just one. I've hardcoded doc2 into my program to get it to work, I'm having trouble looping through it.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q='+searchValue+'&wt=json&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.simple.pre=%3Cem%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fem%3E',
callbackKey: "json.wrf",

success: function( res, req ) {
    for (i=0; i<res.response.numFound; i++) {
        var docId = res.response.docs[i].id;

        //This returns all ids. ex. doc1, doc2 etc.
        alert(docId);


        htmlCode += "<h4>Your search term: "+searchValue+"</h4><p>"+res.highlighting.doc2.content+"</p>";

    }

    //Print code below -- irrelevant for the question.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out from this post: [How do I access properties of a javascript object if I don't know the names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675231/how-do-i-access-properties-of-a-javascript-object-if-i-dont-know-the-names)

I included this in my for loop to get it working:

```
 var hl = res.highlighting;
 var content="";
 Object.keys(hl).forEach(function (key) {
     if(key == docId) {
         content = hl[key].content;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to directly iterate on the `res.response.docs` collection.

e.g. [JQUery JSON Example](http://jsfiddle.net/D9tga/1/)

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function(key, element){
    console.log(element.id);
});
```