# how concatenate object with number javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, concatenation

I have a problem concatenate a number to an object

I need to get [object Object] to concatenate (Button + indexOptionValueToChange), but I get the following

`var indexOptionValueToChange = 1
alert(Button + indexOptionValueToChange)  -----> function Button(nombre){
                                                    this.nombre = nombre;
                                                 }1`

I need to concatenate that (Button + indexOptionValueToChange) == Button1

`alert(Button1) ----> [object Object]`

Comment: Button should be a string only strings can be concatenated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675231/how-do-i-access-properties-of-a-javascript-object-if-i-dont-know-the-names

Comment: Button is a Function, so you've got to return something in order to get it's value.

alert(Button() + indexOptionValueToChange);

function Button(nombre){
   this.nombre = nombre;
   return 'something';
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/5117127/90527)