# Getting the value of an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The array keys are going to be dynamic but there are only two array items.  For example the key `start_location.A` has a value of `London` and the key `start_location.F` has a value of `Manchester`

I can get the values like this

```
var start_location_A = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location.A; 
var start_location_F = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location.F;
```

But the `A` and `F` will be dynamic, meaning the letters will be changing.  How do i get the first & second items in the `start_location` array regardless of key name?  I attempted below but says **start_location.index is not a function**.

```
var start_location_A = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location;
                    start_location_A = start_location_A.index(0);

                    var start_location_F = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location;
                    start_location_F = start_location_F.index(1);
```

How do i solve?

Comment: What about pushing the values of `start_location` into an array, sorted alphabetically (by keys—see tip here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key), and then accessing the array by index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access properties of a javascript object if I don't know the names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675231/how-do-i-access-properties-of-a-javascript-object-if-i-dont-know-the-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate over the keys of the json structure: try this:

```
var arr=[];
var json = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].start_location;
for(var o in json){
     arr.push(json[o]);
}
var start_location_A = arr[0];
var start_location_B = arr[1];
```

it should give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you use a named index, when accessing an array, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.

```
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
person["age"] = 46;
var x = person.length;         // person.length will return 0
var y = person[0];             // person[0] will return undefined
```

One thing you can do is to iterate over object properties using for in loop as @Manish Misra suggested. However  it is not guarenteed that you will get the objects in correct order.
[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280861/659695)