# Accessing Javascript Object Keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm having the hardest figuring out how to this (seems so simple).

I have a Javascript Object as shown here

Output of console.log(data):

```
{"prevExists":false,"pubKey":"b5","ID":"5f1"}
```

I'm trying to access the different key value pairs.

When I try the expected methods, I get back undefined.

I have tried:

```
var pubKey = "pubKey";
data.pubKey
data[pubkey];
data["pubKey"];
```

I know I'm missing something really obvious here.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Can you show us how you define `data`? All 3  should have worked indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access properties of a javascript object if I don't know the names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675231/how-do-i-access-properties-of-a-javascript-object-if-i-dont-know-the-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several ways of accessing keys, depending on which keys you're talking about.

In your example, any of those would work:

```
var data = {
    "prevExists":false,
    "pubKey":"b5",
    "ID":"5f1"
};

// Access all keys of enumerable string-keyed properties
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => console.log(key,data[key]));
// Access all keys of enumerable and non-enumerable string-keyed properties
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach((key) => console.log(key,data[key]));
// Access all keys of enumerable string-keyed properties of your object, its prototype, and all the prototype chain...
for (let key in data)
    console.log(key,data[key]);
```

If you want to have a better understanding of what is an object's property, you can have a look at [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936772/how-to-deep-merge-instead-of-shallow-merge/48579540#48579540) I wrote on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` and a `foreach` loop to access the properties on the object.

```js
var data = {"prevExists":false,"key":"b5","ID":"5f1"};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log('key - ' + key + ' :: value - ' + data[key]);
});
```

Comment: Correct, this would work, as other ways of doing so. I suggest you specify which *properties of the object* are accessed by this method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a reference to your object. Like this:

```
var myObj = { "prevExists": false, "key": "b5", "ID": "5f1" };
```

Then, you can access the elements using their keys:

```
console.log(myObj["prevExists"]);
```

Console exit:

```
false
```

Good luck!

Comment: I suggest you change `myArray` to `data`, because it's definitely not an array ;)

Comment: Oh, sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Object.keys` method

```js
var data = {"prevExists":false,"pubKey":"b5","ID":"5f1"}
console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing yourself with the line var pubKey="pubKey".
There are 2 ways to access object parameters:

```
const data = {"prevExists":false,"pubKey":"b5","ID":"5f1"};
// var pubKey = "pubKey"; This line is not needed
```

1) data.pubKey

If you use the dot operator (.), then you reference it with the key name.

2) data["pubKey"];

If you use brackets ([]), then you use the string that matches the key.

If you add the line:

```
const pubKey = "pubKey";
```

, then data[pubKey] will also work, because it evaluates to data["pubKey"]